Why I always get the same CosmosDb continueToken when use pagination query?
I use continueToken like this:
continueToken = null;

using var feedIterator = linqQueryable.ToFeedIterator();
while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    var response = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync();
    results.AddRange(response);

    if (results.Count >= pageSize)
    {
        continueToken = response.ContinuationToken;
        break;
    }
}            

and I always get the same continueToken and get the same results.
However when I add a sort key for the query, it works.
Do we have to add sort key when we want to use pagination query?

Is the issue that you are getting the same continuation token value? When you say that when you add a sort key "it works", what exactly works? And what didn't work before?

Yes. after I get a sort key like order by name, I could get correct continuation token.

Tried this and without sorting key the continuation token is still new every next response when I add the last continuation token in the GetItemLinqQueryable.

@budong888 Can you share on the post what you consider a correct and incorrect continuation token? How do you know the token without the sort is incorrect?

Yes, because I always get the same continuation token when I add the last continuation token. So, when I use pagination, I always get the same results back.
